# Extern alias error on same assembly and same namespace

Tags: dll, .net-assembly

I have multiple dll which build from different projects in different solutions, build for different logic for different company.

Each of the dll have the same assembly name and same namespace and same version.

Some DLLs have some methods and types with the same name but different implementation and some unique methods and types.

How can I reference those dlls to use in a new project.

I tried to use add all DLLs as reference and change the alias name of each reference alias.

After, add the extern alias for each DLLs.

But I found out extern alias only work the last DLL has been referenced to.

All previous  dlls shown an error
The extern alias 'xxx' was not specified in a /reference option in visual studio 2017.

Any idea what is the cause of this and how to resolve?

Comment: Is this about .NET?

Comment: Yes..it is..the dlls are built in .net framework 3.5. The mian project which reference those dll are developed in vs 2017, built using 4.7.2